# SWIG wrapping c struct pointer to c#

Tags: c#, c, swig, labview

I am having issue to figure out how I can wrap the following c code with swig to access in c#

my.h

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t dimSize;
    double Numeric[1];
} DoubleArrayBase;
typedef DoubleArrayBase **DoubleArray;

/*
* Memory Allocation/Resize/Deallocation APIs for type 'DoubleArray'
*/
DoubleArray __cdecl AllocateDoubleArray (int32 elmtCount);
MgErr __cdecl ResizeDoubleArray (DoubleArray *hdlPtr, int32 elmtCount);
MgErr __cdecl DeAllocateDoubleArray (DoubleArray *hdlPtr);
```

Swig is correctly generating a c# class for DoubleArrayBase, however I can't figure out to modify swig interfaceto be able to do the following in c# so I can access the struct
elements dimSize and Numeric

```
DoubleArrayBase doubleArray = AllocateDoubleArray(10);
var size = doubleArray.dimSize
var ptr = doubleArray.Numeric[0]
```

Here is my interface file:

```
%module MyModule

%{
  #include "MyHeader.h"
%}

%include <stdint.i>
%include <windows.i>
%include <cpointer.i>
%include <swiginterface.i>
%include <typemaps.i>
%include <carrays.i>
%include <arrays_csharp.i>

%apply long  { int32 }
%apply long *INOUT { int32 *}


typedef struct {
    int32_t dimSize;
    double Numeric[1];
} DoubleArrayBase;
typedef DoubleArrayBase **DoubleArray;

DoubleArray __cdecl AllocateDoubleArray (int32 elmtCount);
MgErr __cdecl ResizeDoubleArray (DoubleArray *hdlPtr, int32 elmtCount);
MgErr __cdecl DeAllocateDoubleArray (DoubleArray *hdlPtr);
```

The .h file is an c interface to a LabView code, the DoubleArrayBase struct describes the array and contains a pointer to the data.
So ideally it would be great if I could use swig to automatically wrap the struct and access the array data directly in c#

```
DoubleArray myarray= AllocateDoubleArray(10);
for val in myarray:
   print val;
```

Thanks in advance for any recommendations.

Comment: `double Numeric[1]` is a const array (fixed size), I don't understand how it makes sense to resize it.

Comment: @Charlieface. The functions for memory allocation/resuze/deallocate are generated automatically from LabView.
The structure DoubleArray provide the information to access the LabView allocated array. dimSize is the size of the array, Numeric[1] provide the pointer to the memory allocated by LabView.